# Python: Error during packaging

Tags: python, linux, packaging, pypi

I have made a python package and my project directory looks like this :

```
MyProject
  |-.pypirc
  |- manifest.in
  |- readme.rst
  |- runnable.py # Main File
  |- setup.py
```

The problem is that I have libraries like **tkinter** in the runnable.py which is making problem using requirement installation in linux. How can I make the modifications according to linux ? This is my first time with packaging a module.

My setup.py looks like this-

```
from setuptools import setup
from sys import platform

setup(name='randomdownloader',
      version='0.1.6',
      description='random downloader',
      author='Pankaj',
      author_email='xyz@gmail.com',
      license='MIT',
      py_modules=['runnable'],
      install_requires=[
         'youtube-dl',
         'bs4',
         'BeautifulSoup4',
         'requests',
         'tkinter',
      ])
```

Also it is not getting installing in my OSX during installation, this is the error I am getting.

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-vsthnrl2/urllib/

Answer (score 0):

You could set a function to run `sys.platform` to distinguish between systems, catch the output and extract the first word. Then, accordingly to it, you could run `apt-get install python3-tk`for all Debian-based distros, and for osx

```
xcode-select --install
brew uninstall python
brew install python --use-brewed-tk
```

You should ofcourse run all of these commands via

```
call({command}), preceeded by `import subprocess` in your python script.
```

This will require some tweaking, but it should point you to the right direction.